# Translate attribute values in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I'd like to ask for help in Thymeleaf translation.

I can translate a static value if it is declared in my properties file with `th:utext="#{message.key}"`, but I don't know how to translate an attribute's value on the page.
E.g. the status attribute of an account instance can be "Active" or "Blocked" and I'd like to translate these values.
I use `th:utext="*{account.status}"` to display the status value on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your message as below. See HTML portion for the EL

**Message.properties**

```
# Case 1 #
Active=User is active.
Blocked=User is blocked.

# Case 2 #
account_status_Active=User is active.
account_status_Blocked=User is blocked.
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Case 1 -->
th:utext="#{${account.status}}"

<!-- Case 2 -->
th:utext="#{account_status_ + ${account.status}}"
```

Comment: I had to use `<p th:text="#{gender.__${gender}__}"></p>` (with double underscore) for it to render properly.